Cannot install any modules onto PicoW using Thonny
I run Ubuntu 22.04, and run Thonny - but get different behaviours between the different installs. I think the only one that runs was installed a day or two ago, but is showing it is version 4.1.6. (The snap install shows up in system monitor, but never appears as an app; and the aptitude installation loads and runs, but doesn't show the file manager).
If I set my project to use "local Python 3", I can install packages.
If I configure the project for the PicoW (my target), I can run code on the device, and load new code onto the device and run it, but if I need an additional library, whether a micropython library or another library, when it tries to load the library, I always get the same error - exit status 2.
There is a lot of other text associated, but I cannot copy the text, and it doesn't appear in Terminal if run from there.
A typical example is to try to install the micropython version of pprint.
I cannot seem to determine that the exit status 2 relates to.
I looked in the Thonny folder in .config (which may relate to a version that isn't flatpak although the time/ date could only relate to the flatpack version), and the frontend_faults.log is blank.
The backend.log file didn't seem to have errors or warnings, and the only warning I saw in the frontend.log file was:-
WARNING thonny.ui_utils: Zenity returned code 127 and stderr 'zenity: error while loading shared libraries: <path>/apps/thonny/bin/../lib/liblzma.so.5: file too short\n'

I don't know if this is my issue, but any help so I can get my code working by loading libraries would be appreciated!
Many thanks,
